# Aggregate functions and self referencing table in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Im having a hard time figuring out how to deal with self referencing entities and aggregate functions in Entity Framework. My table looks like this

```
Task
Id    ParentId    PercentageInParent    CompletedPercentage
0     null        null                  null
1     0           60                    null
2     0           40                    null
3     1           80                    40
4     1           20                    60
5     2           50                    80
6     2           50                    90
```

`PercentageInParent` is what percentage of the parent does this subtask form.  I want to look at a task and know what percentage of it is complete by summing its child elements.

Edit
A task(eg. task 1) that has child tasks will have `CompletedPercentage = null` If I want to know its `CompletedPercentage` I want to look down the tree and calculate how the subtasks are completed. In this case task 1 is 44% complete calulated from how far tasks 3 and 4 are completed and the weight they have under task 1.  How would i query that in EF?

Comment: What what 'exactly' is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add another class that does all that mapping...

```
public class TaskMap
{
    public string TaskId { get; set; }
    public string TaskParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Task Task { get; set; }
    public virtual Task ParentTask { get; set; }
}

public class Task
{
    public string TaskId { get; set; }
    public int Progress { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TaskMap> SubTasks { get; set; }
}
```

As you're using `Entity Framework`, you need to think more carefully about how your database is designed... remember it's a `relational` data store, so going through normalisation forms are still important.

With the current design, you will always have multiple records where the `ParentId` column is `null`.  This means that you have a repeating element in your design that needs to be extracted and placed in a separate table.

The new table `TaskMaps` should consist of a composite primary key, that is TaskId and ParentTaskId. This will create your relationship which you can then use to reference the children by implementing something like this.

```
var task = this.Context.Tasks.FirstOrDefault(tasks => tasks.TaskId == "random guid")
task.SubTasks.SelectMany(tasks => tasks.SubTasks)
             .Select(sub => sub.Task);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I have ammended the table so that I have tasks and subtasks. Could you please look at my edited question

Comment: Encountered any issues?

Comment: Subtasks can hav subtasks, Thats my issue really. Although I could limit the subtasks to a certain depth if that would help.

Comment: I just re-read your first comment, and you're not meant to have subtasks held in a different table, you're meant to have a different table mapping 1 task to another. A name that would be more apt is something along the lines of TaskMaps

Comment: I have only one table, and i think its self referencing.  I dont get why you say it isnt normalised?